# Subdivide array based on a condition in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby

The question looks simple but was unable to crack it. A python or ruby function that takes in a list and divide the list into all possible sub list. Members in the sub lists from the original list must have common difference of 1

For example:

```
# [4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15]
```

The list above should return the 3 lists below

```
# [4, 5]
# [7, 8, 9, 10]
# [13, 14, 15]
```

maybe we can use chunk_while

Comment: Any try of yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby's [`Enumerable#chunk_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#chunk_while-method) can be used to create sub-sequences based on two successive elements: (see the doc's first example)

```
ary = [4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15]

ary.chunk_while { |i, j| i + 1 == j }.to_a
#=> [[4, 5], [7, 8, 9, 10], [13, 14, 15]]
```

Comment: Thanks stefan. This solves it perfectly in a ruby way! Hopefully we get some python implementation as well. Thanks for you sharing your knowledge!